# Choose the next closest date after another in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I select the next closest received date from table2 relative to the requested date in table 1? Included the desired result at the end. I am using Oracle SQL.

```
Table1: 
PO           RequestedDate
14888        01/12/2018
14733        02/12/2018
14555        05/12/2018

Table2:
 PO            ReceivedDate
 14888         01/11/2018
 14888         01/14/2018
 14733         2/11/2018
 14733         2/12/2018
 14555         07/23/2018
 14555         09/23/2018

Expected Result:

PO         RequestedDate       NearestReceivedDate
14888       01/12/2018          01/14/2018
14733       02/12/2018          02/12/2018
14555       05/12/2018          07/23/2018
```

Comment: Please provide your current code and describe what is the issue with it

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TABLE_1(PO,REQUESTED_DATE)AS
(
  SELECT 14888, TO_DATE('01/12/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14733, TO_DATE('02/12/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14555, TO_DATE('05/12/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL  
),
TABLE_2(PO,Received_Date) AS
(
  SELECT 14888,    TO_DATE('01/11/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  14888,     TO_DATE('01/14/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14733,     TO_DATE('02/11/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14733,     TO_DATE('02/12/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14555,     TO_DATE('07/23/2018','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14555,     TO_DATE('09/23/2018','MM/DD/YYYY')  FROM DUAL  
)
SELECT T.PO,CAST(T.REQUESTED_DATE AS DATE),X.RR
FROM TABLE_1 T
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT MIN(T2.Received_Date)RR
  FROM TABLE_2 T2
  WHERE T.PO=T2.PO 
   AND CAST(T2.Received_Date AS DATE)>=CAST(T.REQUESTED_DATE AS DATE)
)X
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=81cc657918a214d0f118f870eeb67a3d

Comment: Why use `CAST` when they are already dates?

Comment: Agree. Can be removed

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT t2.receiveddate
         FROM   table2 t2
         WHERE  t1.po = t2.po
         AND    t1.requesteddate <= t2.receiveddate
         ORDER BY
                t2.receiveddate
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (PO, RequestedDate) AS
SELECT 14888, DATE '2018-01-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14733, DATE '2018-02-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14555, DATE '2018-05-12' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (PO, ReceivedDate) AS
SELECT 14888, DATE '2018-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14888, DATE '2018-01-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14733, DATE '2018-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14733, DATE '2018-02-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14555, DATE '2018-07-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14555, DATE '2018-09-23' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PO | REQUESTEDDATE | RECEIVEDDATE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 14888 | 12-JAN-18 | 14-JAN-18 |
> | 14733 | 12-FEB-18 | 12-FEB-18 |
> | 14555 | 12-MAY-18 | 23-JUL-18 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2042190f1fdc2307064f521d5a9c4b7a)*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below solution for your purpose

```
select t1.*, t2.ReceivedDate
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.PO = t2.PO
AND t1.RequestedDate <= t2.ReceivedDate
AND t2.ReceivedDate = (
   SELECT MIN(t3.ReceivedDate) 
   FROM Table2 t3 
   WHERE t3.PO = t1.PO 
   AND t1.RequestedDate <= t3.ReceivedDate 
  )
;
```

*db<>fiddle* [*here*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=deddbbd294c91dc4dc3345fb26290d8a)

Answer (score 0):

As a tricky option you may transform an input dataset to a "vertical" event-like structure, order all the dates and use `match_recognize` to select the row rigth after the `receiveddate`. It doesn't require nested loops compared to the lateral join/cross apply, which significantly affects the performance in case of large dataset in `Table1`, and doesn't multiply the data compared to plain `join` of two tables and `min` aggregation.

Based on the **@MT0**'s data:

> ```
> with t as (
>   select
>     po,
>     /*Prepend numeric constant for stable sort order*/
>     '0_REQ' as src,
>     RequestedDate as dt
>   from table1
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select
>     po,
>     '1_RCV' as src,
>     ReceivedDate as dt
>   from table2
> )
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ *
> from t
> match_recognize(
>   partition by po
>   /*Order by dates, then by event type*/
>   order by dt asc, src asc
>   measures
>     /*Requested date is taken from a request event*/
>     req.dt as RequestedDate,
>     /*Received date is taken from a receive event*/
>     rcv.dt as ReceivedDate
>   pattern (req rcv)
>   define
>     req as src = '0_REQ',
>     rcv as src = '1_RCV' 
> )
> ```
>
> ```
>    PO | REQUESTEDDATE | RECEIVEDDATE
> ----: | :------------ | :-----------
> 14555 | 12-MAY-18     | 23-JUL-18   
> 14733 | 12-FEB-18     | 12-FEB-18   
> 14888 | 12-JAN-18     | 14-JAN-18
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=85e7fc24019f17633c20c1a25bc24d53)*

And just to compare at randomly upscaled dataset: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1ba272505350f7d23d101a17770370a6)